# Javascript: Is there a way to name submit functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return the "value" variable to use on another function but it says that the "getData" is not defined

```js
$('form').submit(function getForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).data('test');
        return value;
    });

    fromForm = getForm();

    function alertForm(){
        alert(fromForm);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-test="1">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form data-test="2">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can't return anything from a submit handler (or any event handler in general). There's no place in your code where you could receive a return value from an event handler. Event handler functions are called from the event queue, and the return value is ignored. The name of the function expression is available inside the function only. If you want to use an event handler as a regular function, you've to declare the function separately, and pass a reference to the event attaching method (`.submit` in your case). It's notable, that you also have to pass a fake event object to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).data('test');
    alertForm(value);
});


function alertForm(fromForm){
    alert(fromForm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to get data-test attirbute value and us it in your **alertForm** Function. You can use a variable to having a greater scop to get this value from the handler of the the submit function but it is not clean. The best way is to get the value directly from the dom as follow.

```
    function alertForm(){
    var fromForm =$("form").data('test');
        alert(fromForm);
    }
```